# Are Roslyn's ".WithFooToken()" calls superfluous?

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn

*I'm trying out Roslyn's code-generation capabilities using LinqPad to run fragments. LinqPad's .Dump() extension method renders a formatted view of the object to the Result pane.*

The code generated by http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/ includes a lot of code that doesn't seem to do much other than add bloat. The following code outputs `return null;` whether the `.WithFooToken(...)` calls are commented out or not.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;

var syn =
    SyntaxFactory.ReturnStatement(
        SyntaxFactory.LiteralExpression(SyntaxKind.NullLiteralExpression)
//          .WithToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.NullKeyword))
    )
//  .WithReturnKeyword(
//      SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.ReturnKeyword)
//  )
//  .WithSemicolonToken(
//      SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)
//  )
;
syn.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString().Dump();
```

Are such calls optional for all languages or only for languages which have sensible defaults built into their Roslyn support libraries?

Comment: Those calls are certainly useful in cases like `return /**/ null;`. As to why they are included always, maybe it's for some reason hard to differentiate the two cases?

Comment: One scenario where I suppose it might matter is when the code is only partially constructed. By default it assume the `return` keyword and the semicolon are there so it adds them by default -- but what if the semicolon isn't typed yet? `syntax = syntax.WithSemicolonToken(SyntaxFactory.MissingToken(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, in simple cases, those calls are not necessary. [The code of RoslynQuoter](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/RoslynQuoter/blob/master/Quoter/Quoter.cs) has the `RemoveRedundantModifyingCalls` option, which I believe is supposed to do exactly what you want. But it's not implemented, [the only usage](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/RoslynQuoter/blob/f6710642a2a40ca012bc0b7d2d73f87dcb67abdc/Quoter/Quoter.cs#L774-L790) is commented out:

```
private void AddModifyingCall(ApiCall apiCall, MethodCall methodCall)
{
    // TODO: this needs scripting
    ////if (RemoveRedundantModifyingCalls)
    ////{
    ////    var before = Evaluate(apiCall, UseDefaultFormatting);
    ////    apiCall.Add(methodCall);
    ////    var after = Evaluate(apiCall, UseDefaultFormatting);
    ////    if (before == after)
    ////    {
    ////        apiCall.Remove(methodCall);
    ////    }
    ////}

    apiCall.Add(methodCall);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

@svick's answer is correct. I just forgot to re-enable that code because Roslyn Scripting wasn't available.

Now that Scripting is public, I have re-enabled that code and updated the website:
http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/

Try out the website right now, and redundant calls like you mention above should be gone (they'll still appear when they're needed to modify trivia/comments/etc).